# multiprocessing with delay of second function

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, multiprocessing

I have a function that write data to a text file, a second function that pull data from the same text file and show a graph. I want to start the second function a few seconds after the first function is started and running both together till both completed. In this way I can get a live graph. The code I have written below starts the two functions simultaneously but the second function cannot see any text file. I need a bit of delay for the second function to give the time the first function to create the text file.

However because the second function (live_graph) needs not just pull data from the text file but also get some parameters (ex. title of the graph) from the 1st function I am not sure if this is the correct way to proceed, as it seems is not possible get a "key" from another function; I got "key not defined". Maybe I have to write to the text file also the parameters?

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time

def writing():    
    numentries = 0
    for text in get_all(newlista, "sentence", "text"):

        if text.lower().startswith( key.lower().split(None, 1)[0] ):
            pass
        elif len(text) > 500:
            pass
        elif len(text) < 80:
            pass
        else:
            on_data(text)

            numentries += 1




  def live_graph():
  #pull data from text.txt
   time.sleep(5)


if __name__=='__main__':

 p1 = Process(target = writing)
 p1.start()
 p2 = Process(target = live_graph)
 p2.start()
```

Comment: why not implement the second one in a way that it blocks until the text file is available?

Comment: how? and then I will able to pull params from the 1st function?

Comment: I have updated the original code with time.sleep and it seems to work. plus I have run the params out of the 1st function and now I am able to use them in the 2nd function. a question: on python web site I read "The actual suspension time may be less than that requested because any caught signal will terminate the sleep() following execution of that signal’s catching routine" it means that I can play safe and put for example 15 secs cos' as soon as the text file has been generated by the 1st function the 2nd function will start anyway?

Comment: Using semaphores between the processes, like say `multiprocessing.Queue` is a lot saner way to handle this problem

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the [`multiprocessing.Queue`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue)

For example (from the docs):

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def f(q):
    q.put([42, None, 'hello'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = Queue()
    p = Process(target=f, args=(q,))
    p.start()
    print q.get()    # prints "[42, None, 'hello']"
    p.join()
```

You could use that in your code like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import time


def writing(q):
    keep_running = True
    numentries = 0
    key = 'something, I assume'
    for text in get_all(newlista, "sentence", "text"):
        # Python lets you do nice comparisons like this,
        # which do what they look like. And make it more
        # obvious that you only want lines of length between
        # 80 and 500 characters
        if 80 < len(text) < 500:
            firstword = key.lower().split(None, 1)[0]
            if text.lower().startswith(firstword):               
                # Note: it is *essential* that in `on_data(text)`
                # after writing to your file you run `file.flush()`
                # or close the file, otherwise the data *may* be
                # buffered and hence, missing, when you go to read
                # the file
                on_data(text)
                q.put(keep_running)

    keep_running = False
    q.put(keep_running)

def live_graph(q):
    keep_running = True
    while keep_running:
        keep_running = q.get()
        # do the graph updates here


if __name__=='__main__':
 q = Queue()
 p1 = Process(target = writing, args=(q,))
 p1.start()
 p2 = Process(target = live_graph, args=(q,))
 p2.start()
```

Comment: I have edited my code to show the acctual first function. I am not sure how to implement your suggestion on it. note in the 1st function I have embedded another 2 functions. "get_all" that extract text from a json file and "on_data" that is actually the function that writes to text file

Comment: @ganesa75 I've updated my code to reflect the code you added. Note that your `key` was previously undefined in the code sample you provide (also double check the indention - your edit mucked that all up) so I did the only thing I could do with it and *guessed*. As a point of advice - most of the time if your code is impossible to run because it's not a [mcve] people will just not run it, so things like indention and using undefined variable names *does* matter :)

Comment: I struggle to paste the code here, I have all the time edit manually the 4 spaces on the right. I have closed file in on_data() but not `file.flush()`. Actually the code must bin the sentences that start with key first word, I have amended it. The code works. However: 1. it takes all my RAM (almost 8gb), is that because is a multi-process? 2. once parsed all the text the code keep running till I close manually the graph, is that normal? 3. some times I see duplication in eclipse stdout console, not in the text file though

Comment: You can highlight your block of code and press the "code format" button `{}`

Comment: As for taking up your RAM, that'll be dependent on what you're doing. Being multiprocess it should be taking up more of your CPU than your RAM. I suspect that you have some rather large objects in one of your processes. I don't know what your data structures look like, so I couldn't tell you. If you search Google for `"python code profiling"` you should be able to find some useful tools. If this answer solves your problem you should probably go ahead and accept it :)

Comment: It does not matter if I have large objects processing. When I run the two processes separately it takes half of the RAM. The writing_parsing function takes 3 GB and the graph one takes 0.5 GB. When I run them  together with code you advised it takes all RAM. 

Plus I have a process that must run first out of the multi-process functions. It run ok, but once the functions are called it run again!! I don't know why, 'cos It's definitely out of the 2 functions and provides a value I need to define in order to run the 2 functions.

Comment: @ganesa75 if you can, I'd recommend posting  your entire `writing_parsing` code (along with any functions that it calls) in a new question and asking why it takes up 3GB of RAM, because that is an *insane* amount of RAM for writing something out to disk. I suspect that your `get_all` function is reading everything from somewhere into memory. If you can turn that into a generator instead then it will save you *tons* of memory.

Comment: I don't really want to post all my code here to ask an advice because it is part of a degree dissertation.. How I can get an advice in a discrete way?

Comment: You may be able to find someone in the [python chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python) with the time/inclination to pair with you using something like [tmate](https://tmate.io/) or Google Hangouts or something.

Comment: I think it should be `if 80 <= len(text) <= 500:` in the `writing()` function. Also what is the point of the local `keep_running` variable in that function?

Comment: @martineau you're right. Or `79 < len(text) < 501`, but I think I'd prefer the round numbers. `keep_running` is sent back to the other thread/process to tell it that there will be no more data written so it can stop looking. Sure you could use something like a naked `True/False`, but I find it's much more helpful to give a `name` to the values.

Comment: Hmm, in that case it might be even better to (just) have a `keep_running, stop_running = True, False` at the top of the function and use the appropriate one were needed. `;-)`

Comment: Why would you need two? `live_graph` is the only one that *uses* the value. I can't see how adding `stop_running` clarifies *anything*.

Comment: I just tested this multiprocess again importing a different sentiment model. And the queue-system is not working now. the graph function kick off too early when the text file has not been created yet. there is way to add some parameter like adding a specific time of waiting?

Comment: Just create your text file *before* you start doing processing. But arguably that's a different question altogether - you shouldn't un-accept an answer just because you've done something different and now you have a different problem. You should ask a new question.