# multi-process Queue - High RAM consuming

Tags: python, memory, multiprocessing

I set a `multiprocessing.Queue` code to run 2 functions in parallel. 1st func parses and writes data to a text file, 2nd function pulls data from same text file and show a live graph. 2nd func must kick off once the 1st func has created a text file. The code works well.

However:

1. It takes almost all RAM (ca. 6gb), is that because is a multi-process? in task manager I see 3 python.exe processes of 2gb each running at the same time, while when I run only the 1st func (the most RAM consuming) I can see only 1 python.exe of 2gb.
2. Once the code has parsed all the text and the graph stopped the processes keep running until I terminate manually the code using eclipse console red button, is that normal?
3. I have a small script that run before and out of the multi-process functions. It provides a value I need to define in order to run the multi-process functions. It runs OK, but once the the multi-process functions are called, it run again!! I don't know why, because it's definitely out of the multi-process functions.

Part of this was resolved in another [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38331616/python-multiprocessing-with-delay-of-second-function?noredirect=1#comment64077820_38331616).

```
define newlista
define key
def get_all(myjson, kind, type)
def on_data(data)
small script run out of the multi-process function


def parsing(q):
    keep_running = True
    numentries = 0
    for text in get_all(newlista, "sentence", "text"):
        if 80 < len(text) < 500:
            firstword = key.lower().split(None, 1)[0]
            if text.lower().startswith(firstword):
                pass
            else:
                on_data(text)
                numentries += 1
                q.put(keep_running)

    keep_running = False
    q.put(keep_running)

def live_graph(q):
    keep_running = True
    while keep_running:
        keep_running = q.get()
        # do the graph updates here

if __name__=='__main__':
    q = Queue()
    p1 = Process(target = writing, args=(q,))
    p1.start()
    p2 = Process(target = live_graph, args=(q,))
    p2.start()
```

***UPDATE***

The graph function is the one that generates two .py processes and once the 1st function terminated the second function keeps running.

Comment: @martin, pls can provide some advice

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I have the expertise with multi-processing needed to do so.